What is the difference between Shimano SM-BBR60 and Shimano BB-MT501
Are these 2 bottom brackets compatible?  Is one 'better' than the other?  Is one more durable than the other, more efficient than the other?
I would guess that the BB-MT501 is meant for dirtier conditions and the seals are better whereas the BBR60 is meant mainly for road use and the seals wouldn't be as good, but it would be less draggy than the MT501.
As far as I can tell, they're both Hollowtech II compatible and 68mm wide and threaded, so they seem identical to me.  If my assumptions above are correct, then if I primarily ride on the road, it would be advantageous to go with the BBR60, but if I primarily ride off-road, then the MT501 would be a better choice, right?

Shimano didn't develop specific BBs for gravel, so I'd assume that road BBs do the job well enough in terms of sealing. It's also possible that it's just a difference of form factor of the cups, that the bearing themselves are the same.

Road Shimano BBs require a 68mm BSA shell, and are mounted directly on the shell.
MTB Shimano BBs require a 73mm BSA shell, and always require a 2.5mm spacer on the drive-side. The external part of the cup is about 1mm thinner, and the thread is longer. They can be mounted on 68mm BSA shells, but in that case, you need to add additional 2.5mm spacer on each side, to have an "apparent width" of 73mm.
In other words, the spacing between the two internal faces of MTB cranks is about 5mm+2.5mm-2mm wider than road ones.
MTB BBs are designed for the larger spacing, road BBs are designed for the less wider one. A MTB BB mounted on a 68mm shell remains a MTB BB, and can only fit MTB cranks (or touring, that are rather designed using MTB standards). If you ignore the dustcap, MTB cups are still thinner than road ones, so you'll need to add spacers to have the same width, but I don't think it's worth it: I suspect the main difference is linked to the dimensions of the cups and the dust cap, rather than the bearings and their sealings.
Also, other detail: BB-MT500/MT501 is Deore range (equivalent to BB-RS501), SM-BBR60 is Ultegra. The MTB equivalent is BB-MT800/MT801.

Ok, I guess that makes more sense.  So, a BBR60 would be compatible with GRX FC-RX600?  BB-RS501 is recommended, but I am wondering if the BBR60 is better?

@JohnDoe Shimano doesn't give any info that allows to state that BBR60 is better, outside marketing talk, but that doesn't mean they are not - it's one range up. My personal experience is that upper ranges last longer - dusty/muddy environments (I'd assume sealing is better), so I take the better ones - the price difference is on top small in absolute terms. Otherwise, if you stay in the same family (road/MTB), parts are interchangeable across product ranges.

Ok, let me backtrack, is BBR60 compatible with the BB-RS501?  If it is, then it is marketed as 105 and in my opinion 105 is better than entry-level.

According to this, https://rocketcyclist.com/shimano-bottom-bracket-bbrs500-vs-bbr60/, they are compatible and the BBR60 is the 'better' option.

They don't do the same thing and are not interchangeable. MT501 is a mountain BB. BBR60 is road. Hollowtech 2 road and mountain BBs made by Shimano are two separate systems that don't interchange, because the dust shield is a fixed length and the cup thickness is not necessarily the same. The spindle length on mountain is longer. So, you can't use a road out one of the box to get to the face-to-face distance a mountain crank needs, and you can't use a mountain one with its dust shield.
Among Shimano's BB lineup, within each compatibility types there's not a ton of variation on which has more aggressive seals. Some are of the opinion that the "old style" form factor like BB-MT501 or BB-RS501 have, which takes the original type of external cup tool (16 notch, Park BBT-9 for example) are more durable because the larger form factor allows for larger. But there's no such thing as opting to put a mountain Shimano BB on a road crank.

They're both Hollowtech II, 24 mm spindle diameter and 68 mm length.  Am I misreading something?  How are they different?

The biggest thing is the length of the inner sleeve. Most MTB have 73mm BB shells. So a MTB BB ships with the longer sleeve and (3) 2.5mm spacers. One spacer is always used on the drive side. IF the MTB has a 68mm shell, all 3 spacers are used 2 on drive side, 1 on left side.  The road BB-R60 has a much shorter inner sleeve and does not require any spacers between a 68mm shell and either cup.  Thus, it does not ship with spacers. If you did put it in a MTB with a 68mm shell then tried to mount a MTB crank, you'd find that the crank spindle was too long and the system wouldn't tighten properly

The BB-R60 also utilizes smaller bearing balls than the MT501.  Some folks feel that the use of smaller bearings contribute to faster wear. They're simply less robust than the larger bearings used in other BB's.  Other than bearing size, there are no published differences. Both models are anodized aluminum cups.  AFAIK there is no published documentation of the amount and types of sealing they each have. Anecdotally, I can report superior longevity and maintained quality with Shimano BB's compared to other brands (Wheels Manufacturing and FSA, notably).
